# Convert Xml to EDI in Azure logic app

Tags: xml, biztalk, azure-logic-apps, edi, enterprise-integration

I am building an application which talks to different enterprises using EDI X12 format. We were doing this using BizTalk on-premises setup, but we were having some problems with that, so we decided to move to Azure Logic apps.

I have setup an Integration Account and uploaded all the Partners, Agreements, Schemas and maps into it. I have also created a Logic app which takes in a:

1. Request Trigger - Post xml to this end point
2. XML Transform - Do a transform based on a map
3. **Convert to EDI - ?? This is the part that I am missing**
4. Send the EDI as Response

Basically, I want to pass in XML and convert it into an EDI file. I have tried the various X12 connectors (Encode, Decode) but they don't convert it into EDI.

I could really use some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is one of the X12 Encode actions available. 
[image]

You can read more about it here: 
[X12 Encode documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-x12-encode)

You say these don't provide the EDI-format. Are you receiving an exception in the Logic App? Or the action executes fine but you don't see the expected EDI? Don't forget the output might be a Base64-encoded string, so you probably need to apply the base64ToString expression on the output of the Encode X12 action.

Something like this:

"body": "@base64ToString(body('Encode_to_EDIFACT_message_by_agreement_name')?['Payload'])"

Comment: That worked! I was missing the base64ToString() part. The encoded string didn't look like a proper EDI format, hence I was getting confused. Thanks a lot.